# How to add function to onChange in Input cmponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, formik

I got form (use formik + andt). Can't find how to add function when Input changes.
for example my mail field:

```
<Form.Item
  help={fieldHelp()}
  validateStatus={fieldValidateStatus('email')}
  label="E-mail"
  name="email"
  >
  <Input
    value={values.email}
    onChange={handleChange} // how to add function here?
    onBlur={handleBlur}
   />
</Form.Item>
```

is it possible to add one more function to `onChange={handleChange}`?
somethiing like this: `onChange={handleChange, myfunction()}` or another way?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can call multiple functions this way

```
onChange={(e) => {
    handleChange(e);
    myfunction()
}}
```

Comment: 'handleChange' is not called, it passed i think ```onChange={handleChange}``` when i call in like this ```onChange={handleChange()}``` i got Formik error

Answer (score 0):

You 'll need to create a custom component for TextInput and manually pass `error` to it...

```
      <MyAppTextInput
        ...
        onChangeText={handleChange('latin')}
        onBlur={handleBlur('latin')}
        error={touched.latin && errors.latin}
      />
```

- 

```
const onYourFieldChange = fieldName => {
  handleChange(fieldName);
  YourCustomFn();
};
```

Comment: thank you. 'handleChange' is function inside Formik. and when I tryed do like this ```onChange={onYourFieldChange('email')}```  formik validation not work. when I do like this ```onChange={handleChange}``` validation work fine. But may be its something wrong with my code... :(